# storage strategy of OCR / Parquet file

Tags: hadoop, ocr, parquet, bigdata

let's assume that my HDFS block size is equal to 256Mb and that i need to store 20Gb of data on OCR/Parquet file(s), is it better to store all the data on one OCR/Parquet File, or is it better to store it on many ORC/Parquet files of 256Mb (HDFS Block Size) ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: HDFS I/O works better if the files are stored in the multiples of the block size.  Too small or too large sized files do not perform well. I would consider a 20GB file as a large sized file.  As for the processing engines (HIVE, Spark, Mapreduce), keeping the files split greatly improves the performance. Even though large files are splittable by Hadoop, it is better to keep them split which will improve the initial startup time.

Comment: Hello , first of all thanks for you answer.
otherwise why manually splitting the files will improve  the initial startup time ? what's the difference if M/R jobs do that ?

Comment: Hi Mehdi. Please find my answer below. The system does not allow to add a long answer under comments.

Comment: thanks a lot !, i'll answer below !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mappers and Reducers are responsbile for handling your core data processing needs. The resource manager is responsible for identifying the data involved in a particular job  based on the input and the input types  you provide and it tries to divide it among multiple tasks and manage the execution of those jobs.  However, you need to make sure that the data you feed is optimized and divided equally so that the resource manager can allocate them to the Mappers.

Note: There is lot more to M/R optimization than dividing the data in equal chunks. However, it is the first right step.

Parquet and ORC are usually secondary formats for data loaded from source (TXT, CSV, JSON, etc). The source files usually are too large or too small (in KBs. We have many scenarious where we have to deal with this). So, we minimally process it (cleanup, date conversion, etc)  and store it as Parquet / ORC files using MR/HIVE jobs. We use mapred file size parameters to specify the file size. It is usually in multiples of HDFS block size (64MB in our case).

The advantages are

1. Data divided equally to multiple Mappers reduces map and reduce job skews.
2. Your hadoop platform resource utilization is much more even.
3. Disk spill, sort, and I/O issues are minimized while using appropriate sized blocks.

Other notes

1. ORC / Parquet are highly specialized formats specifically written for fast reads, writes, and searches.
2. When combining ORC/Parquet formatting with compression algorithms like Snappy, LZO, etc. The read and write performance improves a lot in most cases.

Comment: thanks a lot i found your answer very useful ! and i agree with you in the overall answer, but why do i need to make sure that the data i feed is divided equally in order that the resource manager can allocate them to the Mappers ? isn't the responsability of the  ressource manager to break them automatically into splits ?

i think that ORC/Parquet are good in reads but no in writes.

thanks in advance for you answers :),

Comment: You are welcome.

Resource Managers are not magical tools :) it makes the best effort to divide up the job. At the end of the day, you need an efficient system to handle your workload. So, every decision from choosing the compression format, input types, partitioning, bucketing, etc matters. Understanding these concepts help architect a better solution.

Comment: The key points I advocate for keeping files in smaller sizes are

1. The data is more evenly split. Resource Manager has a easy job of creating tasks. Generally performs well than utilizing one large file.
2. Moving data around manually or through distcp is faster due to parallelization. 
3. Better I/O and networking performance. 
 
Concepts like partitoning and bucketing looks at file splitting from a functional standpoint. I highly recommend you to take a look at that as well.

Comment: Cool. If you are satisfied with the answer, can you please accept it? It encourages the community to be active.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work